# Find a string on a cell in table A and copy the found into another table B

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

Which formula can I use for this case?

I want to find with a formula a string (for example "koala"), which is a part of a larger string (for example "koalalalalo") which is in any column of line 2 in table A and copy the complete contents of the found cell in a cell of table B. Before that I don't know in which column the string will be therefore I need a formula which searches in all columns of line 2 to find the string.

Comment: The found what?  That word, that column, the one just below,...?

Comment: I edit it – sry, youre right. That information was missing.

Comment: HLOOKUP with wild cards should do it.

Comment: Ok cool. Thank you! 

Can you tell me one thing more: How can I find only cells which are not an "exact match" like "koala" and only cells with longer strings like"this-koala-is"?

Comment: Hlookup with wildcards.  `=HLOOKUP("*"&"koala"&"*",2:2,1,FALSE)`

Comment: This one works for me: `=WVERWEIS("*"&F1&"*";Data!4:4;1;FALSCH)` (german version). But it gets me exact matches too :/

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=HLOOKUP("*"&F1&"*"; Data!4:4; 1; 0)
```

[image]

---

> But it gets me exact matches too

```
=HLOOKUP("*"&F1&"*"; FILTER(Data!4:4; Data!4:4<>F1); 1; 0)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use `HLOOKUP` and wildcards for example:

`=HLOOKUP(search_key,range,index,[is_sorted])`

[image]

---

**References**:
- [HLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375?hl=en)